# Continuous deployment with Bitbucket on Azure not working

Tags: git, azure, bitbucket

I set up git continuous deployment with bitbucket on my Azure website according to [this blogpost](http://sandrinodimattia.net/blog/posts/continuous-deployment-with-windows-azure-websites-and-bitbucket/)

I go through all steps without any problems but when I `git push` to bitbucket no Azure deployment happens...

If I push to my azure git url, deployment works as usual.

Anybody else that have had this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: What error do you get when it fails to push?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yesterday we deployed to bitbucket.org a change to [send the Authorization header with our POST service](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/5610/post-service-does-not-send-authorization) that may have broken our integration with Windows Azure.

I've rolled back the change so that we can investigate.

Does it work for you now?

Comment: Oh that's interesting. That probably explains http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/azuregit/thread/da676230-5c62-42c2-b9f2-b9d694285a10! Would you mind commenting there as well with more info? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @nicolasv have you by any chance re-applied this change recently?  I last did a deployment on 17th Jan and it worked, now I have tried one today (22nd Jan) and Azure is not picking it up.  If I push to Azure from git it works, so I suspect it is a BitBucket issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set bitbucket deployment up after pushing directly to your git repo on Azure? You'll need to FTP in and empty the deployments folder and then refresh the deployment tab on the portal. You'll then be able to link your bitbucket account again and it should just work then

Comment: tried this, and it didn't solve the issue. Though i noticed that for private/public repos where i was admin, integration happened smoothly. It's only for repos where i had only read-write-access that i couldn't setup the deployment. Actually, to test this hypothesis, i made a fork of a repo where i had only rw-access (in the fork, i'd be admin automatically), and then tried setting up deployment with this fork. It worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the solution in all cases, but for me it's one of the hypotheses I've tested and found true:

I noticed that for private/public repos where I was admin, integration happened smoothly. It's only for repos where I had only read-write-access that I couldn't setup the deployment from version control (that is for Bitbucket and Azure Websites).

Actually, to test this hypothesis, I made a fork of a repo where I have only rw-access (in the fork, am automatically made admin), and then tried setting up deployment with this fork. It worked fine!

Note that for all the repositories I tried linking to (whether private or not, and whether the linking worked or not) I had read-write access. Though, I believe the ultimate setup should only need read-access to a repo. Am yet to isolate the actual problem...